# Don't allow American express card in Expresso store

Tags: expresso-store, stripe

Is it possible to set Expresso Store to not accept American Express payments? The client us using stripe, and within stripe there is no option to disallow Amex.

I can block american express cards using JS but this is not a very robust solution.

I thought it might be possible to pass payment[card_type], but this has no effect.

would there be a hook i can use to validate before it'd passed to the payment processor?

Many thanks,

Tom

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are not wanting to accept AMEX? Stripe doesn't charge higher fees for AMEX over Visa/MC/Discover in most cases unless you have $80k+ monthly sales and you have negotiated lower rates for transactions then the normal 2.9% + $.30 fee have I ever seen a difference between the different card types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built in to Store that would allow you to prevent a particular card type from being processed at the module level.

If the gateway required the [card type](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#card_type) you would be able to use a select and omit any card types you did not want to support. So for example you could do

```
<select name="payment[card_type]">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="visa">Visa</option>
    <option value="mastercard">MasterCard</option>
    <option value="discover">Discover</option>
</select>
```

if you only wanted to support Visa, MasterCard and Discover but not Amex. Stripe however does not require the card type to be submitted for a successful transaction. I also don't think that submitting the wrong card type would cause the transaction to fail as a result (even if you added `data-stripe="card_type"`). Having the select however would give a visual cue to the end user that Amex is not accepted.

If a JS option is out of the question you should be able to use the [store_payment_request_start](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/extension_hooks.html#store_payment_request_start) hook to do any additional processing/validation before the transaction to sent to the payment processor.

Comment: I went with the JS option for the moment, and will look into the hook as a more secure method.  Thanks!